# Angular check service instance

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, angular-components

I'm trying to implement a `canDeactivate` guard. For that purpose I need to check properties of the service instance on the component. However, since this service may be injected using different aliases I try to check all properties to be an instance of a service.

```
canDeactivate(
    component: Component,
    currentRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    currentState: RouterStateSnapshot,
    nextState ? : RouterStateSnapshot
): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {

    let tabsService;

    const componentProps = Object.entries(component);

    console.log(componentProps);

    for (let i = 0; i < componentProps.length; i++) {
        if (componentProps[1] instanceof TabsService) {
            console.log(true);
            tabsService = componentProps[1];
            break;
        }

        console.log(componentProps[1] instanceof TabsService);
    }

    ...
}
```

However, this results in all `false`s.[image]

How do I do this? Or should I get an instance in other way? I know that it's bad to call one thing in different aliases, but this is inevitable with tons of DIs and team development (IMHO).

Comment: isn't the service a singleton?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be `componentProps[i][1]` everywhere instead of `componentProps[1]`, shouldn't it ?

Comment: yeah. I've realized that after detailed logging of every bit of code

Comment: Any idea how this could be implemented if it was a module-level provider? I.e. get an instance of service that is provided in module that contains a component. The problem is that `canDeactivate` is used on component and this component is being passed in function.